# can we have wifi direct api working in 2.3 version

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-2.2-froyo, android-wireless

hi i am developing a app which will use proximity to pair other persons.

I can either use Bluetooth or Wifi Direct. 
After some research i found out that Android ICS has API's for Wifi direct but if my application needs to work on older phones i need some API which can help me, please guide me.

Does Google provide any API to be included to the sdk to be used for older android versions or I am wondering if it is possible ??

I am reluctant to use Bluetooth because of it's slow connectivity.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

I think that API was added on Ice Cream Sandwich (14). So you have no chance to use this API in older Android versions.

Comment: That's not possible. The vendors have to install some drivers to support those features.