# How to develop/code WIFI Direct with Android 2.36 (Gingerbread)?

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

Some phones have Wifi Direct apps while having Android OS 2.3.x. But Wifi direct APIs is supported by Android 4.0 or later.

So Can I develop(code) for Wifi direct with Android 2.3, is there any such library or way to do so (for e.g using NDK or else)? Pls give the links or detail! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see the following links:

[WiFi Direct for Android Version 2.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000286/wifi-direct-for-android-version-2-3).

[can we have wifi direct api working in 2.3 version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8381831/can-we-have-wifi-direct-api-working-in-2-3-version).

The answer is NO. You can use built-in wifi direct apps in devices with Android 2.3. Note that in official website, Google only supports Wifi Direct API from Android 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking no, Wi-Fi Direct is not supported on Gingerbread. Devices running this version of Android will neither be able to act as group owners, nor will they be able to connect to other Wi-Fi Direct devices using Wi-Fi Direct calls.

That said, it is possible for a Gingerbread device to connect to a Wi-Fi Direct device using its standard Wi-Fi interface.  On Wi-Fi Direct devices, the WifiP2pManager class defines a createGroup method that makes the device a Group Owner that can not only accept connections from other Wi-Fi Direct devices but also legacy Wi-Fi ones. To achieve this, the device effectively acts as an access point and can be connected to by any Wi-Fi device, including a Gingerbread device.

You would need to devise a mechanism to transfer the SSID and key from the Wi-Fi Direct device to the Gingerbread device.  With this, the device could then use Wi-Fi to programatically connect to the Wi-Fi Direct group.